# Why would not use the declare keyword for interface or type at typescript declaration file?

Tags: typescript, declaration, keyword, declare, .d.ts

When I am using type declaration file, it should use the declare keyword before, example like:

```
declare var a: number
declare let a: number
declare const a: 1
declare function a(b: number): string
declare class A { b(): number }
declare namespace A {}

type A = number
interface A { b?: string }
```

Why would not use the declare keyword before interface or type?

> quote https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1940

Comment: The compiler already knows, that `interface` and `type` don't have a run-time impact. So `declare` is redundant and leaving it out shorter. Why make life harder? :)

Comment: Thanks, declare is used to tell the compiler that at runtime exists something and the compiler erase all of them.